# Categorizing the text

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, data-science

I am trying to decide if given URL is any kind of event or not. By *Event* I mean *Event* such as `conference`, `summit`, `convention` etc. Here is preliminary algorithm I have for it:

I found out following(look at the end) tokens and if they are in the Content of the page (I find content from HTML using third party library) then I mark it as Event. Of-cousre, this doesn't end here. I assign weight to each token, weight signifies - how strong this token could tell that given url is an event. e.g. if I find `conference` in the content, it will have better confidence in telling me that it's an event compared to `registration` - which could appear frequently in  other kinds of articles too.

So, I calculate score for each article as follows:
Sum of (frequency of token  in the content *  its weight). And then if this score is `> EVENT_THRESHOLD` then I mark the article as Event. The problem with this approach is: if I get, lets say 20 occurrences of 'event' (which has poor confidence i.e. low weight) the score jumps and breaks the `EVENT_THRESHOLD` and marks the article as event. Is there any better way to implement this ? I hope I am not reinventing the wheel. Thanks. P.S. I am no data science guy :(

Tokens for Event:

```
("event", 0.4),
("workshop", 1.0),
("registration", 0.4),
("register", 0.3), 
("conference", 1.0),
("tickets", 1.0), 
("summit", 0.5), 
("speaker", 0.5),
("training", 0.5),
("session", 0.4),
("convention", 1.0),
("webinar", 1.0),
("duration", 0.6)
```

Comment: Yes, you are reinventing the wheel. There are tons o scientific articles out there regarding event detection. What most of them have in common is that they use some kind of TF-IDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are definitely reinventing the wheel. The best would be that you look at Naive Bayes models if you want to make your life simple. It is very similar to your model but has a statistical foundation.

The basic idea is that you learn for each type of event a the prior probability `P(conference)`, which is basically the fraction of documents from class `conference`. Additionally you calculate the probability that a specific event's page contains a word, e.g., `registration` which is calculated as fraction of `conference` pages containing this word `P(registration|conference)`. Note: if the word is not contained you need to incorporate the inverse probability `1-P(registration|conference)` 
The product of all probabilities gives you the (unnormalised) probability that a page belongs to a certain event category.

If you consider the words  `registration`, `conference`

The probability for `conference` the probability of the document `{registration}`  would be

```
P(registration|conference)* (1-P(conference | conference) )*P(conference)
```

where the probabilities estimated from this document would be

```
P(registration|conference)= 1
P(conference | conference) =1
```

However, there are many more algorithms you can use, e.g., multi class SVMs, decision trees,.....

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for direction. I will dive right for learning ML.

Comment: I implemented this algorithm and now about to train my model. How do I continuously train my model, what are the approaches that are prevalent?

Comment: You just need to calculate the number of occurences of each word continously. Once you need to classify a ew count you can calculate the probability which is pretty cheep.